# Why can't rails see my application.css file in the app/assets/stylesheets directory

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get my css to work in a very simple rails application. All I'm trying to do is use:

```
<% stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

in my default layout, but I am getting an error:

```
JSON::ParserError in Home#index
```

Home is the name of my controller, and index is the name of my action. Is there something in particular I need to tell my application for the stylesheet_link_tag to work?

Comment: Sounds like your JS interpreter might be broken. Try installing [`NodeJS`](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Comment: Do I need to install it and then include it as a gem in my gemfile? @RichPeck

Comment: Nope, just on your system.

Comment: This might not be the problem, which is why I wrote as a comment not an answer :D

Comment: you were correct @RichPeck. I needed to install nodejs on my system..I don't totally understand why but thanks for the tip!

Comment: It's because of [Exec:JS](https://github.com/rails/execjs), which is what Rails / Ruby passes JS code to to parse it

Comment: Would you mind if I wrote it as an answer?

Comment: not al all @RichPeck

Answer (score 0):

try this

**<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>**

im using it in rails 4

Comment: that didn't work for me. Is your stylesheet link tag in your application.html.erb file under layouts?

Comment: yup, my application.html.erb is under my views/layouts folder

Comment: did you specify anything in your controller?

Comment: I get it now, use <%= instead of <% on your code. Your css is not loaded because you use <% instead of <%=

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to install [`nodeJS`](http://nodejs.org) on your system.

The reason is because of the `ExecJS` module requires a JS parser to manage any JS/JSON that your app may have. The error is typical of Windows systems, but is also present on Linux / Mac too.

Once `nodeJS` is installed, restart any command prompts & it should work.